# Can gold-badge owners get the possibility to undo a bump by a revision?

Tags: feature-request, old-questions, bump

Every now and then (a couple of times a day) in the tags I follow an old question appears that has been bumped to the front page by a small revision. Sometimes this also happens by [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/168269), but in much fewer cases.

I've been paying attention to the effect of bumping for quite a while now. What I see is that too often it leads to an influx of meaningless, repeated answers that don't surpass comment quality. We have enough of that type of noise on Stack Overflow.

I think that gold-badge owners are well capable of assessing what bumping will do to a question. Questions that are very likely to only attract new useless answers are the ones that -

- are about old, now virtually irrelevant versions of products.
- are about an error that occurs very often in a wide variety of situations, while the answerer only jumps on the exception message, not regarding OP's specific scenario. (The "I had this too" type of answer).
- have a title that doesn't reflect the actual question while new answerers only read the title.
- already have a correct and complete answer which just was never upvoted/accepted (esp. such answers should not get buried in noise!).
- are off-topic questions (broad/opinion/unclear) that spark wild guesses or new opinions and that should have been closed long ago.

Also note that when the revision is minor (spelling/formatting), these question don't really deserve new attention, at least not more than the next one that doesn't need correction. What deserves to be bumped up is new content from users that keep posts up-to-date or in some other way significantly improve them. And of course meaningful new answers.

So therefore my question: can we give gold-badge owners the possibility to "unbump" a bumped question so they can prevent the accumulation of noise on Stack Overflow? To prevent abuse this could be restricted to, say, 5 a day.

Comment: We could start by at least giving *moderators* the ability to make such non-bumping edits. Currently, even diamond moderators can't do things like retag questions without being extremely disruptive.

Comment: There's a similar declined [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page) on Meta that asks about more general no-bump edits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I agree that this would be nice, but there's a massive potential for abuse, there.

The bump makes sure all changes have a chance to be reviewed by the community.
If it were possible to "unbump", or edit without bumping, it could lead to plain old junk edits that don't get spotted and taken care of...

A possible solution would be to make it so you can only unbump something someone else edited, but I'm not sure that's safe enough...

Comment: I like the extra safeguard.

Answer (score 0):

While I am actively curating, I filter content on activity, not on new-ness.  There are plenty of FGITW users keeping an eye on the new stuff, so I consider it more meaningful if I monitor where most are not looking.

I would not want this bump-denial feature implemented.  I would not like to see activity stiffled.  Sometimes, the only way I find old gems is because someone else made a good/bad edit (maybe it got lost because the title isn't very searchable).

1. If these old edits are meaningless, let's address the editor (an opportunity to groom the user).
2. If the answers to these old questions are under-appreciated or seemingly overlooked, you can help by upvoting (reward the user).
3. If the new answers to these old questions are meaningless, add no new value, deviate too far from the scope of the question, or are not actually answers, then we must do our appropriate curation by downvoting, flagging, and commenting for a net positive outcome (both improving content and helping to groom users' posting behaviors).
4. If these old questions are simply a bad fit for Stack Overflow or are in any way closable, then gold badgers should use their expertise to appropriately close these pages (this would halt all unwanted activity in a more permanent fashion while contributing to good curation).

Just because the technology in the question is old, unpopular, or deprecated, it doesn't mean that the content shouldnt be improved, revisited, peer-reviewed.

Activity is one of the cornerstones of the continued success of Stack Overflow, so let's not try to stand in the way of that.

Comment: I have a lot to say in response. First, I also filter on activity, for the exact reason that I'm interested in new questions/answers but also, well, activity. It's filtering on new posts that would hide these revision. Secondly, how would un-bumping "stiffle" activity? It's not that I propose to do that to each and every revision. Sure, maybe every now and then a gem shows up, IMO that doesn't outweigh the problems I describe.

Comment: Then, as for your points: all of them are actions when it's too late. The revision has already happened. Points 2, 3, and 4 are thing I do very frquently, 1 somtimes. Of course we can only close questions when there's a suitable duplicate. It takes a lot of effort to find these, which I can't always work up. Esp. question under my 4th bullet point are worth this effort.

Comment: It's my assumption that gold badgers can judge whether the revision needs any curation. Errors are also made in dupe hammering, moderation and what have you.

Comment: "_Secondly, how would un-bumping "stiffle" activity?_" if you unbump it, then I would not see it and therefore you are preventing my potential curation. "_Then, as for your points: all of them are actions when it's too late._" Better late than never.  Also, hammering and dupe voting is not the only way to close a page.  Curation and community management is just like parenting -- if you have children that don't take risks or never make mistakes, they are missing opportunities to grow, the parent(s) miss opportunities to parent, and life is pretty dull.

Comment: "_Errors are also made in dupe hammering, moderation and what have you._" Absolutely. This is why the community benefits from bringing attention to every shred of new activity -- so that errors can be scrutinized and remedied.

Comment: The attention is given. Then, sometimes, it's deemed not necessary, is all.

Comment: I like to think of my role in Stack Overflow to be similar to a macrophage or a white blood cell.  Sometimes I flow toward cases that need my attention, sometimes not.  The important thing is that I keep moving through the system.  If gold badgers and SME continue to navigate freely (unimpeded) and do their best work, then the content and the community will only get richer.

Comment: OK, your focus is on visibility, mine on preventing noise. I respect that. I think we both like to keep SO as rich as possible.